# New form elements break whole program in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I got a problem with a program a co-worker gave to me before he left our company. My boss told me to continue his work and so I do now. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition.

I have a form with 4 buttons and a few text fields/checkboxes. Whenever I try to add new elements like button/checkbox/anything, the buttons simply break. They just don't work anymore. Even if I remove those new elements, the program stays broken. The only solution is to re-copy the whole program from a backup I did manually.

For example:
The program runs fine, i can click one of the buttons to open a FileDialog, import a file and read from it, text appears in textbox.
But after adding a new element like described above, nothing works anymore. When I hit F5, the program starts normally but when I try to click a button, nothing happens, like the buttons don't have a function anymore.

I added breakpoints where the button-function gets called, but it looks like, the program never reaches those. I have simply no idea what went wrong or what could cause those problems.

Edit: I tried adding new elements directly via the form.designer.vb. It works, but i still want to fix the problem with the designer editor.

I hope you can help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you getting any error messages at all?

Comment: No, like described above, just nothing happens. Even if I add a simple textbox via MsgBox to the first line of the button-function, nothing happens when I click it.

Comment: Okay, it works now. It looks like the program doesn't like "handles" and seems to ignore them. I added a handler for one of the buttons manually in Form1_Load, and it works now.